# Outlook and GMail - Subfolder under Inbox or [GMail]

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap

I am configuring an Outlook 2016 client to work with GMail via IMAP. As Google uses labels to categorise messages I am a little confused as to whether I should create my folders (in Outlook) under the Inbox node or under the [GMail] node.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the [Gmail] node with the Inbox one by going to:

Outlook preferences > Accounts > Select your account > Advanced > under SERVER tab go to the voice "IMAP Root Folder" and put there: `[Gmail]`

Comment: This URL provides more details about changing the IMAP root folder and how it interacts with labels.   https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/gmailroot.htm

Answer (score -1):

There is no such a thing as 'preference' because the GMAIL folder is created automatically for the gmail account which uses IMAP. When you have other email accounts that use mail.domain.com or POP (incoming server) and SMTP (outgoing server) a folder for each different account is created in INBOX

Answer (score -1):

On Outlook for mac - Delete your gmail Accounts. Add your Accounts back by adding new account and entering the email address but when on the next screen click the link in the upper right corner "Not gmail?" on the next screen at the bottom select pop/imap at the bottom. From there follow the rest of the on screen prompts. Adding folders in outlook should be back as it once was.